# RDS launches with default group via aws cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-rds

I am trying to create RDS instance from a snapshot using AWS cloudformation. Despite specifying security group, cloudformation still launches the RDS instance with default security group. 
I have attached my code snippet here, am I missing a value it is expecting?

```
RDSInstance:
Type: "AWS::RDS::DBInstance"
Properties:
  DBInstanceClass: db.m4.2xlarge
  DBInstanceIdentifier: TestRDS
  VPCSecurityGroups: ["sg-09r75bf44xxxx7689"]
  DBSubnetGroupName: dev-db-subnet
  DBSnapshotIdentifier: arn:aws:rds:us-east-1:333400xxxx866:snapshot:devrds1-new
  Tags:
  -
    Key: "Name"
    Value: "DBforTesting"
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Fn::ImportValue](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-importvalue.html) to get your security group which was created separately:

```
VPCSecurityGroups: 
 - { "Fn::ImportValue" : "sg-09r75bf44xxxx7689" }
```

If security group is declared in your file it should be referenced with `Ref`:

```
VPCSecurityGroups: 
 - { "Ref" : "SecurityGroup" }
```